# Accept Clipboard permission request in chrome using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, clipboard

I have want to copy some content and paste it and analyze it.

I have Headless Linux.

When I copy it. I tried to paste it via `pyperclip` it gave me
`not implemented` error. Then I tried and installed xclip.

This Gave me error `xsel: Can't open display: (null)`

So I tried another way. to use a javascript snippet to run it in python to get clipboard data. that's  the code

```py
javascript_script = '''
    var done = arguments[0];
    setTimeout(async () => {
  const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
  console.log(text);
  done(text);
}, 3000);

     '''

driver.execute_async_script(javascript_script)
```

That's running good but require to accept allow clipboard. but i cannot find how to enable it.

Need help to resolve with

- xclip
  or
- allow the clipboard access automatically

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to allow clipboard in **Chrome** + **Selenium** + **Node.js**:

```
const {Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const {Options} = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

const options = new Options()
options.setUserPreferences({
    profile: {
        content_settings: {
            exceptions: {
                clipboard: {
                    ['http://YOURURL,*']:
                        {
                            "expiration": "0",
                            "last_modified": Date.now(),
                            "model": 0,
                            "setting": 1
                        },
                }
            }
        }
    }
})

const driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(options).build()
```